# how to add a property in a single object in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add an element in the object-like

`{ "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "sunt aut", "body": "quia et suscipit" }`

**I want like below**

`{ "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "sunt aut", "body": "quia et suscipit" "image": "image-name.jpg" }`

```
let {postDetail} = useParams();
const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postDetail}`;
const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        setDetails(data => [...data, {"image":`${data.id}`}]);
    })
    
},[]);
```

Comment: It's not an "array-like", it's an object. `{ ...data, image: "image-name.jpg" }`

Comment: not working the code actually

Comment: You need to tell what "not working" means. Error messages? Wrong output (if so, what?)

Comment: Its should be like `setDetails({ ...data, {"image":`${data.id}`}});`

Comment: don't get any error but not get output data in console it's totally empty

Comment: `setDetails({ ...data, "image":`${data.id}`});` dont get any output data in console

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you override the value of `data`.
Take a look at this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {   // Rename this from "data" to "res" (or anything you like)
         setDetails([...details, { image: res.id }]);
      });
}, []);
```

Comment: What's the error message? Or is the console output empty again?

Comment: `console.log(res)` gives the older data not added image element in the object

Comment: Please take a look at this StackBlitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rfxkyq?file=src/App.js

Comment: here I see image added but old data are not available when add the image

Comment: please check the link project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yaqrry?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FPostDetail%2FPostDetail.js